# How to use a button to populate data without doing a postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following ASP.net button inside my GridView:

```
<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" ID="btnShow" CssClass="btnSearch" Text="View All" CommandName="ViewAll" OnCommand="btnShow_Command" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' />
```

The code-behind is:

```
protected void btnShow_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;

    if (e.CommandName == "ViewAll")
    {
        index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        DataTable cacheTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["ResultsTable"] as DataTable;

        string column = cacheTable.Rows[index].Field<string>("Guideline");
        string test = BookingResults.Rows[index].Cells[7].Text;
        string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(column);

        ResultsDiv.InnerHtml = html;
    }
}
```

The ResultsDiv is shown in a popup using the JQuery:

```
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Click the button event!
    $(".btnSearch").click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).val() + " Clicked");
        e.preventDefault();
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });
});
```

When I navigate to the page, the generated HTML looks as follow (there are multiple rows with the same button in the column):

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl33$g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9$BookingResults$ctl224$btnShow" value="View All" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl33$g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9$BookingResults$ctl224$btnShow&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ctl33_g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9_BookingResults_ctl224_btnShow" class="btnSearch" />
```

What is happening now, is when I click the `View All` button it displays the alert, when I click OK, it displays the popup for a split second and refreshes the page.

How can I modify the code-behind/JQuery so that I can click on any of the button, and it will display the alert and show the popup every time and not do a postback?

Comment: You are mixing two worlds, with the ASP.NET PostBack loading data into the Page, and jQuery trying to display it. 
What is actually happening is, you display the Popup first (jQuery, on the client), then do the PostBack to populate the data. 
Can you think of a different approach?

Comment: @Alexander How would I display it correctly? I am not too sure of a different approach. Can I do a postback JUST inside the popup so the whole page doesn't reload?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle. You need to have a feeling for "what happens when". 
One different approach MIGHT be, if it isn't too much data, to prepare one invisible content DIV for each button while building your Grid, then let jQuery display them individually. No postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first thing you need to do even before alert is  e.preventDefault();

```
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Click the button event!
    $(".btnSearch").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopproPagation();
        alert($(this).val() + " Clicked");

        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });
});
```

As what i think that the alert lets the event do its default job first.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge- Sure, if it still does not work, please share the html or an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Having the same issue still :/ What HTML would you like to see?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Ok, it would help to see the html which is generated on the browser on thich this script is getting applied.Another thing is that you have a onclick event handler in the tag itself which is handled by WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions function . Does this function also contain e.preventDefault() too ?

Comment: the `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` is generated in the HTML but I never coded it in. I will post the code on a site for you to review. The code for the function and the button only? It is a Visual Web Part if that helps.

Comment: I have to use something other than ASP:Button because I removed the JQuery completely and it does a postback regardless.

Comment: Try adding ` OnClientClick="e.preventDefault()"` in the ASP Button once, may it it will help.

Comment: I tried changing to OnClick rather than RowCommand and it still is doing a full postback :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge -http://forums.asp.net/t/1184772.aspx?Prevent+postback+during+button+click

Comment: It stops the POSTBACK and displays the popup the first time and then doesn't show it anymore after that. No matter how many clicks. :/ That was the issue I was having.

Comment: This answer won't help at all, because it ignores the initial PostBack problem.